# CURL -T (--upload-file equivalent) in Python Requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am looking for an equivalent of curl:

```
curl http://my_url:8080 -H "Content-type: application/csv" -T test.csv
```

I am especially looking for an alternative to `-T filepath`.

I've read the [request documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/) and all the easy convert method like https://curl.trillworks.com/ or [uncurl](https://github.com/spulec/uncurl) doesn't convert the parameter `-T`.

Comment: It'd be helpful to show what you tried. For example, have you attempted using the `files=` parameter, as described in http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file?

Comment: ..."show", not "describe". That is, show us the code, and show us the specific failure you encountered when using it, as described in the [mcve] page in the Help Center.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer by calling my curl request with verbose.

Use `request.put()` with the content of your file in the parameter `data`.

```
 response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=open(path_file,'r').read())
```